# Different versions of Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll

Tags: c#, sharepoint

There seem to be two versions of Sharepoint's DLL.

I am trying to add a folder, using clientContext and updating the list. But I get an error "use SPFileCollection.Add()". I have seen heaps of these types around the place (starting with "SP") but they're not in my version of Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll.

What am I missing? Is there more than one version?

Comment: Maybe you need the client dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure @[leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541/leppie) is right: you need the Microsoft Client Object Model libraries.

Download the redistributable from Microsoft
( http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21786 ). Then you'll want to reference the **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll** in your project.

And just to be thorough, Microsoft has a good introduction to the [SharePoint Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx).

---

**UPDATE:** I found an SP1 version of the Client Object Model redistributable. Probably should go with that instead! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2508825

Comment: I've done that and still have the same issue, it seem's that Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll is needed in some cases

Comment: @ChrisFletcher Can you elaborate on the scenario where you need the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll ?